# How to convert a rectangular region from one page of a multipage PDF to PNG? Clipping/Cropping problem

Tags: pdf, png, ghostscript, postscript

I can convert an entire page of a PDF with ghostscript to PNG, but clipping a rectangular region does not work. Here is what I currently have:

```
gs -dSAFER -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=png16m -r200 -dFirstPage=45 -dLastPage=45 -sOutputFile=outfile.png -q -c 0 0 640 150 rectclip -f infile.pdf
```

This does convert the entire page 45 to a PNG file, but it does not crop or clip it to the specified region.

Later I found out that with the -g option I can set the size of the resulting PNG file. For example adding -g640x150 will make the output file exactly that size in pixels. It clips the lower left hand corner of the page. And with -c "<> setpagedevice" I can move the clipped rectangle to the right by 100 pixels and up by 200 pixels.

There is one remaining problem. I don't want the clipped area to go beyond the page boundaries. How can I make sure to stay inside the page boundaries?

Answer (score 0):

The `clip` operator works by appending the current path to the existing clipping path, consequently the size of the clipped area can only be reduced and never expanded.

If the -g option sets a larger size than the page boundaries, then there may be undrawn portions in the final output.